# How to export a 3D quiver plot from MATLAB with matlab2tikz correctly?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, matlab, matlab2tikz

Using [matlab2tikz](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22022-matlab2tikz-matlab2tikz) version 1.0.0 the MATLAB code

```
scatter3([0 1],[0 1],[0 1]);
hold on
quiver3(0,0,0,1,1,1,0);
matlab2tikz('test.tex');
```

produces

[image: MATLAB plot]

and the tex file *test.tex*. Plotting this file without changing anything in tex via

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\input{test}
\end{document}
```

produces

[image: Tex plot]

because matlab2tikz converted the arrow in the matlab plot to

```
\addplot3 [arrow1] coordinates{(0,0,0) (0.9,0.9,0.9)};
```

In this case scaling the arrow by 1/0.9 in the MATLAB code or correcting the coordinates manually in tex helps. But often scaling the arrows before exporting the plot doesn't even help, it still gets plotted with the same wrong length. The *scaling factor* always seems to differ from plot to plot.

What can I do?

Comment: An attempt to overcome this problem is here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/324024/how-to-manipulate-coordinates-data-in-tikz-pgfplots

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in matlab2tikz version 1.0.0 by [this answer here](https://github.com/matlab2tikz/matlab2tikz/issues/939). Using the [current development version](https://github.com/matlab2tikz/matlab2tikz/tree/develop) solves the problem.